# Lerna always lists all packages ready to publish when running workflow of Github actions

Tags: github, npm, github-actions, lerna, monorepo

Lerna does not correctly detect packages change during running workflow of Github actions.

1. If I make none packages related changes, commit and run`lerna updated`locally. it tells me **No changed packages found** which is correct and expected.
2. If I make package related changes, commit and run `lerna updated` locally. it tells me found **x packages ready to publish** which is also correct and expected.

**However, if I push the commit based on `1 or 2`. the step which I run `lerna updated` in my github actions workflow always tells/lists me all the package are available to publish which is wrong.**

**I am wondering why and how to fix it ???**

**here is what I see locally if I made none packages related changes**

```
lerna notice cli v3.20.2
lerna info versioning independent
lerna info Looking for changed packages since @xxx/bar@2.3.4
lerna info No changed packages found
```

**here is what I see on workflow log after pusing the none packages related changes to Github**

```
> lerna updated -l

lerna notice cli v3.20.2
lerna info versioning independent
lerna info Assuming all packages changed
@xxx/bar  v2.3.4 packages/Bar
@xxx/foo  v1.4.4 packages/Foo
@xxx/hulk v1.0.4 packages/Hulk
lerna success found 3 packages ready to publish
```

**here is my workflows**

```
name: Publish
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  unit-test:
    name: UnitTest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm test

  publish:
    name: Publish NPM Packages
    needs: unit-test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
      - run: npm ci
      - run: git config --global user.email "xxx"
      - run: git config --global user.name "xxx"
      - run: npm run updated
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}}
```

**here is my package.json**

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "lerna": "^3.20.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "updated": "lerna updated -l",
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

**here is my lerna setting**

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "version": "independent",
  "command": {
    "publish": {
      "allowBranch": "master",
      "conventionalCommits": true,
      "message": "chore(release): updated release notes and package versions"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about lerna so this is a long shot, but does lerna try to read git commits to determine if it should publish or not? If that's the case, you might want to try using the `fetch-depth` input of `actions/checkout` to checkout more than just 1 commit (which is the default). See [here](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/master/action.yml#L27-L29).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After hours of debugging. I found the answer myself and thanks to @peterevans for the tip

You have to combine both

- [`fetch-depth: 0`](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/master/action.yml#L27)
- [`run: git fetch --depth=1 origin +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`](https://github.com/actions/checkout#fetch-all-tags)

so that all git history and tag are exposed to lerna.

Answer (score 6):

Wow - cannot believe that I've finally found a fix to the same issue - huge thanks!

I see this as a big issue with github actions (specifically @actions/checkout), and thus I've informed them here: https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/217

I've also informed the `lerna` folks here: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2542

and `semantic-release` people here: https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/issues/1526

Thanks again! You've helped me save a lot of time & fix an annoying issue, and I hope I'll help others with this too. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

There is also the option [include-merged-tags](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/commands/version#--include-merged-tags)

So this should also solve the problem:

```
lerna updated --include-merged-tags
```

or for publishing:

```
lerna publish --include-merged-tags
```

Comment: What is the use case for NOT using this flag?  Why would one ever want to not include-merged-tags ?  Or, in other words, why is this not the default behavior and we could EXCLUDE with a flag?

Comment: @GaryB96 I believe it was an oversight of the dev and instead of potentially breaking things for people he made it an option.

Answer (score 1):

Documenting my findings about this issue.

@eded found the correct issue, which was that by default, actions/checkout fetches only 1 commit for performance reasons. Therefore, lerna does not have access to the version tags (which are often several commits back) and assumes that all packages have changed by default :

```
lerna info Assuming all packages changed
```

You therefore need to force actions/checkout to get all commits and tags, by using the input `fetch-depth: '0'`

This is all you need to do, as actions/checkout was [corrected](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/217#issuecomment-634802933) to fetch all commits *and* tags since v2 after this issue surfaced.

This might be a performance issue as your monorepo grows.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you use `git tag xxx` without `-m` parameter. If you execute `git tag` yourself instead of using `lerna version` or `lerna publish`, you should add `-m` parameter to make the tag annotated.
Ref: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1357#issuecomment-438162152