# why is Lerna always publishing all my packages?

Tags: typescript, lerna

I set up a small project for my "open-sourced" libraries [here](https://github.com/fes300/open-source) that uses Lerna to automate publishing such projects. For some reason I can’t understand every package gets bumped every time `lerna publish` runs in the CI.

### Expected Behavior

only packages actually changed get published

### Current Behavior

all packages always get published

### Possible Solution

‍♂️

### Steps to Reproduce (for bugs)

download [my repo](https://github.com/fes300/open-source), run `lerna updated` and both of my packages are always there

lerna.json

```
{
  "packages": ["packages/*"],
  "version": "independent",
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "command": {
    "publish": {
      "ignoreChanges": [
        "**/CHANGELOG.md",
        "**/node_modules/**",
        "**/package.json",
        "**/*.md",
        "**/*.spec.*",
        "**/*.stories.*"
      ],
      "conventionalCommits": true,
      "message": "chore(release): publish",
      "registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org"
    }
  }
}
```

### Context

my semver is not very coherent

### Your Environment

typescript repository

| Executable | Version |
| ---: | :--- |
| `lerna --version` | 3.22.1 |
| `npm --version`  | 6.14.4 |
| `yarn --version` | 1.22.4 |
| `node --version` | 13.12.0 |

| OS | Version |
| macOS Catalina | 10.15.5  |

Comment: I found my answer here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180630/lerna-always-lists-all-packages-ready-to-publish-when-running-workflow-of-github

Answer (score 4):

Possibly a little late, but this is what worked for me:

```
lerna publish --include-merged-tags
```